# Get last 6 months from in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

How can I get the date range in jquery from current date, I have done following in java, need to replicate it in jquery

```
Datetime sixMonthsFromNow = Datetime.now().addMonths(-6);
sortByQueryString = '&fq=lastmodified:['+sixMonthsFromNow.format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'hh:mm:ss\'Z\'')+'+TO+NOW]';
```

Comment: Date Range for what ?

Comment: take a look at momentjs

Comment: from now, need a date range to pass on to SOLR to get the results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript style for this piece of code (jQuery not required) :

```
var now = new Date();
var sixMonthsFromNow = new Date(now.setMonth(now.getMonth() - 6));
var sortByQueryString = 
    '&fq=lastmodified:[' + sixMonthsFromNow.toISOString() + '+TO+NOW]';

// &fq=lastmodified:[2013-11-27T08:57:10.089Z+TO+NOW]
```

Comment: You're welcome ! Feel free to set this answer as accepted if it fits to your needs.