# Get new age on a particular date through jQuery/ javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have a scenario that the page displays user's age (30) at particular date (example, 09/10/2015). Now on selection of new date, I have to pre-populate new age field with the business logic of when the new date is greater than 6 months/ 182 days (example 03/11/2016) from the given date, then age should be +1 (example age would be 31).

I know we can achieve this by following code. But I am looking for an optimal way of getting new age on selection of new date.

```
var newDate = $("#NewDate").val();
if (newDate != null && newDate != '') {
    var currDCD = new Date($("#CurrentDate").val());
    var newDCD = new Date(newDate);
    var yearsDiff = newDCD.getFullYear() - currDCD.getFullYear();
    var day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    //Get last years days difference
    var daysDiff = Math.floor((newDCD.setFullYear(currDCD.getFullYear() + (yearsDiff - 1)) - currDCD) / day);
    var currAge = parseInt($("#CurrentAge").val());

    //Set new owner age
    $("#NewAge").val(currAge + (daysDiff > 182 ? yearsDiff : yearsDiff-1));
}
```

Comment: have you tried something similar to this? var newDate = new Date($("#NewDate").val());
var sixMonthsFromNow = new Date(newDate .setMonth(newDate .getMonth() - 6));  then just compare the two dates. Credit goes to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23883749/get-last-6-months-from-in-jquery

Comment: This is check to six months from now, but my requirement is dynamic and have to set new age based on number of years difference and then number of months or days difference in last year year. Since we cant set new age +1 for the date 01/10/2016 when my current age is 30 at 12/31/2015.

Comment: You could use momentJS, anytime I go near date times in JS I use this library http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should give you the age rounded down or up depending on the month:

```
function getAge(birthday) {
    var diff = new Date(new Date() - new Date(birthday))
    return diff.getFullYear() - 1970 + (diff.getMonth()>=6?1:0)
}
```

where birthday is anything that can be used in the constructors of [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: Wow! this is what I was looking for. Thanks Danilo, appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Updated and working code. Thanks Danilo.

```
var newDate = $("#NewDate").val();
if (newDate != null && newDate != '') {
    var currDCD = new Date($("#CurrentDate").val());
    var newDCD = new Date(newDate);
    var diff = new Date(newDCD - currDCD);
    var ageDiff = diff.getFullYear() - 1970 + (diff.getMonth() >= 6 ? 1 : 0);
    var currAge = parseInt($("#CurrentOwnerAge").val());
    $("#NewAge").val(currAge + ageDiff);
```